# How to display a popup for every checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a pop up box to be displayed for every checkbox checked of a class. The pop up box will also have a checkbox on it. So for every checkbox checked on the pop up box the value of the checkbox should be pushed to an array.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('input[name="cases"]:checked').each(function() {
  cases.push($(this).attr('itemLabel'));
  console.log("cases",cases); 
  $("<div>Rule: "+$(this).attr('itemValue')+"<br><input type='checkbox' id='applyToall' name='applyToall'/><label>Apply to all?</label><br></div>").dialog();
  if($('input[name="applyToall"]:checked')) {
    ApplyToAll.push($(this).attr('itemLabel'));
    console.log("ApplyToAll",ApplyToAll)
  }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/drxjhgeq/

Comment: Are you want as that : 
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

Comment: http://i63.tinypic.com/15cftoh.png

Comment: no i want them to be added to a array.

Comment: @fiddle Please provide your HTML code as well

Comment: added jsfiddle if that works.